# Problems Connecting to MS SQL Server Through R DBI Package

Tags: r, sql-server, macos, dbi

I'm trying to setup a connection to a SQL Server from my Mac using the 
Microsoft OBDC Driver and the DBI package.

The connection establishes, however character fields, even those that have no special characters, return garbled.  The database is proprietary so I'm limited as to what actual output I can show.  Numeric fields return fine.

Some other notes.

- If I submit a query, I'm able to receive a record set using the correct table.  For example the below query returns results, and the column name is correct.  The data in the column is garbled

```
> dbGetquery(con, "Select name from tb1", n = 1)
Warning: Pending rows
              name
1     CalteMtrSeda
```

- `dbListTables()` also returns garbled output, even though as shown above I can receive output from the table referencing it by name.

  - `dbListTables()` returns the correct number of tables, but the names are not intelligible.

```
grep("tb1", dbListTables(con), value = TRUE)
character(0)
```

- Output from my `con` object

```
> con
<OdbcConnection> user@ExpectedDataBase
  Database: NameIWouldExpect
  Microsoft SQL Server Version: 13.00.1742
```

** Updated to include pattern.

I'm getting every other character returned.  From the example above.
`CalteMtrSeda == CharlotteMotorSpeedway`

This is the first time I've attempted to connect to this database from a Mac.

Comment: `Garbled` typically means that `varchar` fields were used to store non-English text instead of `nvarchar` and the program that tries to read the data (your program) uses a different codepage from the program that wrote the data. You'll have to post an example of the table schema, sample data and what you get back

Comment: As for `proprietary database` all of them are. That doesn't mean you can't post examples. You can create a *new* database with similar schemas, similar data and post those. In fact, creating a new, simple database is a great way to troubleshoot as it allows you to isolate the parts that cause the problem.

Comment: Finally, try reading the data using SSMS (Windows Only) or Azure Data Studio (despite the name, it's a cross-platform database IDE). What does the data look like?

Comment: First check.  In Azure Data Studio the data looks fine.  No issues with either the table names or any of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be related to R3.6. Reverting to R3.5 fixed the issue.  Link to relevant issue in `odbc` repo

https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/283